# Match subpatterns in any order

Tags: php, regex, perl

I have long regexp with two complicated subpatters inside. How i can match that subpatterns in any order?

Simplified example:

```
/(apple)?\s?(banana)?\s?(orange)?\s?(kiwi)?/
```

and i want to match both of

```
apple banana orange kiwi
apple orange banana kiwi
```

It is very simplified example. In my case `banana` and `orange` is long complicated subpatterns and i don't want to do something like

```
/(apple)?\s?((banana)?\s?(orange)?|(orange)?\s?(banana)?)\s?(kiwi)?/
```

Is it possible to group subpatterns like chars in character class?

UPD Real data as requested:

```
14:24 26,37 Mb
108.53 01:19:02 06.07
24.39 19:39
46:00
```

my strings much longer, but it is significant part. Here you can see two lines what i need to match.
First has two values: `length` (14 min 24 sec) and `size` 26.37 Mb.
Second one has three values but in different order: `size` 108.53 Mb, `length` 01 h 19 m 02 s and `date` June, 07
Third one has two `size` and `length`
Fourth has only `length`
There are couple more variations and i need to parse all values.

I have a regexp that pretty close except i can't figure out how to match patterns in different order without writing it twice.

```
 (?<size>\d{1,3}\[.,]\d{1,2}\s+(?:Mb)?)?\s?
 (?<length>(?:(?:01:)?\d{1,2}:\d{2}))?\s*
 (?<date>\d{2}\.\d{2}))?
```

NOTE: that is only part of big regexp that forks fine already.

Comment: Using commas helps... `match both apple banana orange kiwi apple orange banana kiwi` hmm... both, you say?

Comment: I need only two of them banana and orange. So i say "both"

Comment: Maybe explode your string with `\s`, sort it, implode and then match pattern?

Comment: oh, i undestand i lost a formating when i post question. So "both" means "both line" that i provide.

Comment: See ["And" in regular expressions '&&'](http://ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/and-in-regex/).

Comment: You need to tell us the *real* problem. Although it is possible, it doesn't look like a regular expression is the right tool for this.

Comment: @Borodin, if i will provide all my regexp it will be a lot of drama.

Comment: I would like to see the real data that you have to match. You say you have *" long complicated subpatterns"*, and I think you should simplify the problem first.

Comment: The regex you show will match *anything*, because everything is optional. You must explain better what you need.

Comment: My sample regexp don't match anything. Only 4 fruits and only if it exists. Updated post with real data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An other way with your edit:**

I assume that a line can not contain more than one date, length or size, and I use a simple alternation:

```
$subject = <<<'LOD'
14:24 26,37 Mb
108.53 01:19:02 06.07
24.39 19:39
46:00
LOD;

$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
^
(?>
    (?> (?<date>   (?> 0[0-9] | 1[012] ) \. (?> [0-2][0-9] | 3[01] )(?! \h+  Mb) ) 
      | (?<length> (?> (?>01:)? [0-9]{1,2} : [0-9]{2} )              )
      | (?<size>   [1-9][0-9]{0,2} [.,] [0-9]?[1-9] (?> \h+  Mb)?    )
    )
    (?> \h | $ )
){1,3} $
~xm
LOD;

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r($matches);
```

`\h` : horizontal white character (space or tab)

**The conditional way:**

You can use a conditional `(?(condition)true|false)`:

```
(banana)? orange (?(-1)|\g<-1>)
```

where `-1` is the relative position of the capturing group (i.e: the last) and `\g<-1>` refers to this capturing group.

You can translate this conditional pattern by: *if the first capturing group on the left captures something then do nothing else match the capturing group*

Example with your sample text in PHP:

```
$subject = <<<'LOD'
apple banana orange kiwi
apple orange banana kiwi
LOD;

$pattern = '~(apple)?\s?(banana)?\s?(orange)?\s?(?(-2)|\g<-2>)\s?(kiwi)?~';

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

**Notice:**

You can easily reuse subpatterns with the oniguruma syntax `\g<...>`:

```
\g<2>    # second capturing group of the pattern
\g<-2>   # second capturing group on the left from the current position
\g<+2>   # the same on the right
\g<size> # refer to the subpattern of the named capture (?<size>...)
```

If you want, you can build a pattern using a definitions section, example:

```
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
# definitions 
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<b> banana )
    (?<o> orange )
    (?<fruit> \g<b> | \g<o> | kiwi | apple )
)

# pattern
\g<b> \s \g<o> | \g<o> \s \g<b>

~x
LOD;
```

With this kind of tools, you avoid to repeat the content of a sub pattern.

Comment: Thanks, i understand and will check. But i still need to write `banana` twice... Look my updated post. My conditions not just words so i want to avoid duplicating.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following adaptation of ["And" in regular expressions '&&'](http://ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/and-in-regex/) will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>){
    print "Matched: $_" if /^(?=.*\bapple\b)(?=.*\bbanana\b)(?=.*\borange\b)(?=.*\bkiwi\b)/
}

__DATA__
apple banana orange kiwi
apple orange banana kiwi
apple orange banana
kiwiorange bananaapple
```

Output:

```
Matched: apple banana orange kiwi
Matched: apple orange banana kiwi
```

This effectively creates a logical *AND* in the regex where the order of the conjuncts is not significant.

Comment: It also says `Matched: kiwiorange   bananaapple`

Comment: @Borodin - Excellent catch.  Fixed.  Thank you.

Comment: It still says `Matched: kiwi orange   banana apple` which probably isn't what is wanted. Although it's hard to tell. It looks like he wants `ABOK` or `AOBK` but not `KOBA` etc.

Comment: @Borodin - Although it's not perfectly clear, it *appears* the OP wants to match all terms w/o regard to their order.

Comment: Maybe, but I doubt it. It also says `matched: kiwi plum orange pineapple grape banana melon apple strawberry`, which I think is probably wrong, but who knows?

Comment: I can't figure out your idea. Can you explain? You don't need to write code for me, just explain a method please. You using \b but in unacceptable in my case. See my updated question. May be it helps to understand me more clear.

Comment: Oh, i figured it out. I will try it now.

Comment: @ikegami - Thank you for adding those important pragmas.